# User select option not updating with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following select option:

```
<select class="items" id="items" name="option">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

With the following JS:

```
var numOfItems;
var total = 75;

$('.items').on('change', function() {
  var get = $('#items option:selected').val();
  alert(get);

  if (get === '1') {
    numOfItems = 50; // random values
  } else if (get === '2') {
    numOfItems = 10;
  } else if (get === "3") {
    numOfItems = 20;
  }

  $('#new_text').html(total + numOfItems + " USD");
});
```

Now it functions correctly and displays what it needs to as the user selects from the varying options, however, once I start to style the select, it essentially stops functioning. I spent all day on this (basically) yesterday and can't figure out what's going on.

This is what I'm styling it to (slight change):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
   <label class="select-label">Number of items (max 3):</label>
   <select class="items cs-select cs-skin-rotate" id="items" name="option">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

---

[image]

Any help is appreciated! Here's the other half of my code (HTML) and if you need to see the linked CSS files, I'll gladly post them:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cs-select.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/cs-skin-rotate.css" />
```

This is the portion I'm trying to update:

```
<h2 style="margin-top: 40px;">Total amount $<span id="new_text">35 USD</span></h2>
```

Update**

**cs-select.css:**

```
/* Default custom select styles */
div.cs-select {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

div.cs-select:focus {
    outline: none; /* For better accessibility add a style for this in your skin */
}

.cs-select select {
    display: none;
}

.cs-select span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 1em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

/* Placeholder and selected option */
.cs-select > span {
    padding-right: 3em;
}

.cs-select > span::after,
.cs-select .cs-selected span::after {
    speak: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.cs-select > span::after {
    content: '\25BE';
    right: 1em;
}

.cs-select .cs-selected span::after {
    content: '\2713';
    margin-left: 1em;
}

.cs-select.cs-active > span::after {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(180deg);
}

div.cs-active {
    z-index: 200;
}

/* Options */
.cs-select .cs-options {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.cs-select.cs-active .cs-options {
    visibility: visible;
}

.cs-select ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.cs-select ul span {
    padding: 1em;
}

.cs-select ul li.cs-focus span {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Optgroup and optgroup label */
.cs-select li.cs-optgroup ul {
    padding-left: 1em;
}

.cs-select li.cs-optgroup > span {
    cursor: default;
}
```

**cs-skin-rotate.css:**

```
div.cs-skin-rotate {
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: 700;
    width: 300px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 30em) {
    div.cs-skin-rotate { font-size: 1em; width: 200px; }
}

.cs-skin-rotate > span,
.cs-skin-rotate .cs-options li {
    background: transparent;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -200px;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% -200px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 30em) {
    .cs-skin-rotate > span,
    .cs-skin-rotate .cs-options li {
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% -100px;
        transform-origin: 50% 50% -100px;
    }
}

.cs-skin-rotate > span {
    border: 1px dashed #c0c6c4;
}

.cs-skin-rotate.cs-active > span {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg);
}

.cs-skin-rotate > span::after,
.cs-skin-rotate .cs-selected span::after {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
}

.cs-skin-rotate > span::after,
.cs-skin-rotate.cs-active > span::after {
    content: '\e012';
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,-90deg);
    transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0) rotate3d(0,0,1,-90deg);
}

.cs-skin-rotate ul span::after {
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
}

.cs-skin-rotate .cs-selected span::after {
    content: '\e00e';
    font-size: 1.5em;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.cs-skin-rotate .cs-options {
    background: transparent;
    top: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cs-skin-rotate .cs-options ul {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cs-skin-rotate .cs-options li {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg);
}

.cs-skin-rotate.cs-active .cs-options li {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg);
    transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg);
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.cs-skin-rotate .cs-options li:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
    transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

.cs-skin-rotate .cs-options li:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.cs-skin-rotate .cs-options li:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
    transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

.cs-skin-rotate .cs-options li:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.cs-skin-rotate.cs-active .cs-options ul li {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.cs-skin-rotate .cs-options li span {
    padding: 1em 0;
}

.cs-skin-rotate .cs-options li span:hover,
.cs-skin-rotate .cs-options li.cs-focus span,
.cs-skin-rotate .cs-selected span {
    opacity: 0.8;
    background: transparent;
}
```

**selectFx.js:**

```
;( function( window ) {

    'use strict';

    /**
     * based on from https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll/blob/master/jquery.nicescroll.js
     */
    function hasParent( e, p ) {
        if (!e) return false;
        var el = e.target||e.srcElement||e||false;
        while (el && el != p) {
            el = el.parentNode||false;
        }
        return (el!==false);
    };

    /**
     * extend obj function
     */
    function extend( a, b ) {
        for( var key in b ) { 
            if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                a[key] = b[key];
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    /**
     * SelectFx function
     */
    function SelectFx( el, options ) {  
        this.el = el;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );
        this._init();
    }

    /**
     * SelectFx options
     */
    SelectFx.prototype.options = {
        // if true all the links will open in a new tab.
        // if we want to be redirected when we click an option, we need to define a data-link attr on the option of the native select element
        newTab : true,
        // when opening the select element, the default placeholder (if any) is shown
        stickyPlaceholder : true,
        // callback when changing the value
        onChange : function( val ) { return false; }
    }

    /**
     * init function
     * initialize and cache some vars
     */
    SelectFx.prototype._init = function() {
        // check if we are using a placeholder for the native select box
        // we assume the placeholder is disabled and selected by default
        var selectedOpt = this.el.querySelector( 'option[selected]' );
        this.hasDefaultPlaceholder = selectedOpt && selectedOpt.disabled;

        // get selected option (either the first option with attr selected or just the first option)
        this.selectedOpt = selectedOpt || this.el.querySelector( 'option' );

        // create structure
        this._createSelectEl();

        // all options
        this.selOpts = [].slice.call( this.selEl.querySelectorAll( 'li[data-option]' ) );

        // total options
        this.selOptsCount = this.selOpts.length;

        // current index
        this.current = this.selOpts.indexOf( this.selEl.querySelector( 'li.cs-selected' ) ) || -1;

        // placeholder elem
        this.selPlaceholder = this.selEl.querySelector( 'span.cs-placeholder' );

        // init events
        this._initEvents();
    }

    /**
     * creates the structure for the select element
     */
    SelectFx.prototype._createSelectEl = function() {
        var self = this, options = '', createOptionHTML = function(el) {
            var optclass = '', classes = '', link = '';

            if( el.selectedOpt && !this.foundSelected && !this.hasDefaultPlaceholder ) {
                classes += 'cs-selected ';
                this.foundSelected = true;
            }
            // extra classes
            if( el.getAttribute( 'data-class' ) ) {
                classes += el.getAttribute( 'data-class' );
            }
            // link options
            if( el.getAttribute( 'data-link' ) ) {
                link = 'data-link=' + el.getAttribute( 'data-link' );
            }

            if( classes !== '' ) {
                optclass = 'class="' + classes + '" ';
            }

            return '<li ' + optclass + link + ' data-option data-value="' + el.value + '"><span>' + el.textContent + '</span></li>';
        };

        [].slice.call( this.el.children ).forEach( function(el) {
            if( el.disabled ) { return; }

            var tag = el.tagName.toLowerCase();

            if( tag === 'option' ) {
                options += createOptionHTML(el);
            }
            else if( tag === 'optgroup' ) {
                options += '<li class="cs-optgroup"><span>' + el.label + '</span><ul>';
                [].slice.call( el.children ).forEach( function(opt) {
                    options += createOptionHTML(opt);
                } );
                options += '</ul></li>';
            }
        } );

        var opts_el = '<div class="cs-options"><ul>' + options + '</ul></div>';
        this.selEl = document.createElement( 'div' );
        this.selEl.className = this.el.className;
        this.selEl.tabIndex = this.el.tabIndex;
        this.selEl.innerHTML = '<span class="cs-placeholder">' + this.selectedOpt.textContent + '</span>' + opts_el;
        this.el.parentNode.appendChild( this.selEl );
        this.selEl.appendChild( this.el );
    }

    /**
     * initialize the events
     */
    SelectFx.prototype._initEvents = function() {
        var self = this;

        // open/close select
        this.selPlaceholder.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
            self._toggleSelect();
        } );

        // clicking the options
        this.selOpts.forEach( function(opt, idx) {
            opt.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
                self.current = idx;
                self._changeOption();
                // close select elem
                self._toggleSelect();
            } );
        } );

        // close the select element if the target it´s not the select element or one of its descendants..
        document.addEventListener( 'click', function(ev) {
            var target = ev.target;
            if( self._isOpen() && target !== self.selEl && !hasParent( target, self.selEl ) ) {
                self._toggleSelect();
            }
        } );

        // keyboard navigation events
        this.selEl.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( ev ) {
            var keyCode = ev.keyCode || ev.which;

            switch (keyCode) {
                // up key
                case 38:
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    self._navigateOpts('prev');
                    break;
                // down key
                case 40:
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    self._navigateOpts('next');
                    break;
                // space key
                case 32:
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    if( self._isOpen() && typeof self.preSelCurrent != 'undefined' && self.preSelCurrent !== -1 ) {
                        self._changeOption();
                    }
                    self._toggleSelect();
                    break;
                // enter key
                case 13:
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    if( self._isOpen() && typeof self.preSelCurrent != 'undefined' && self.preSelCurrent !== -1 ) {
                        self._changeOption();
                        self._toggleSelect();
                    }
                    break;
                // esc key
                case 27:
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    if( self._isOpen() ) {
                        self._toggleSelect();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } );
    }

    /**
     * navigate with up/dpwn keys
     */
    SelectFx.prototype._navigateOpts = function(dir) {
        if( !this._isOpen() ) {
            this._toggleSelect();
        }

        var tmpcurrent = typeof this.preSelCurrent != 'undefined' && this.preSelCurrent !== -1 ? this.preSelCurrent : this.current;

        if( dir === 'prev' && tmpcurrent > 0 || dir === 'next' && tmpcurrent < this.selOptsCount - 1 ) {
            // save pre selected current - if we click on option, or press enter, or press space this is going to be the index of the current option
            this.preSelCurrent = dir === 'next' ? tmpcurrent + 1 : tmpcurrent - 1;
            // remove focus class if any..
            this._removeFocus();
            // add class focus - track which option we are navigating
            classie.add( this.selOpts[this.preSelCurrent], 'cs-focus' );
        }
    }

    /**
     * open/close select
     * when opened show the default placeholder if any
     */
    SelectFx.prototype._toggleSelect = function() {
        // remove focus class if any..
        this._removeFocus();

        if( this._isOpen() ) {
            if( this.current !== -1 ) {
                // update placeholder text
                this.selPlaceholder.textContent = this.selOpts[ this.current ].textContent;
            }
            classie.remove( this.selEl, 'cs-active' );
        }
        else {
            if( this.hasDefaultPlaceholder && this.options.stickyPlaceholder ) {
                // everytime we open we wanna see the default placeholder text
                this.selPlaceholder.textContent = this.selectedOpt.textContent;
            }
            classie.add( this.selEl, 'cs-active' );
        }
    }

    /**
     * change option - the new value is set
     */
    SelectFx.prototype._changeOption = function() {
        // if pre selected current (if we navigate with the keyboard)...
        if( typeof this.preSelCurrent != 'undefined' && this.preSelCurrent !== -1 ) {
            this.current = this.preSelCurrent;
            this.preSelCurrent = -1;
        }

        // current option
        var opt = this.selOpts[ this.current ];

        // update current selected value
        this.selPlaceholder.textContent = opt.textContent;

        // change native select element´s value
        this.el.value = opt.getAttribute( 'data-value' );

        // remove class cs-selected from old selected option and add it to current selected option
        var oldOpt = this.selEl.querySelector( 'li.cs-selected' );
        if( oldOpt ) {
            classie.remove( oldOpt, 'cs-selected' );
        }
        classie.add( opt, 'cs-selected' );

        // if there´s a link defined
        if( opt.getAttribute( 'data-link' ) ) {
            // open in new tab?
            if( this.options.newTab ) {
                window.open( opt.getAttribute( 'data-link' ), '_blank' );
            }
            else {
                window.location = opt.getAttribute( 'data-link' );
            }
        }

        // callback
        this.options.onChange( this.el.value );
    }

    /**
     * returns true if select element is opened
     */
    SelectFx.prototype._isOpen = function(opt) {
        return classie.has( this.selEl, 'cs-active' );
    }

    /**
     * removes the focus class from the option
     */
    SelectFx.prototype._removeFocus = function(opt) {
        var focusEl = this.selEl.querySelector( 'li.cs-focus' )
        if( focusEl ) {
            classie.remove( focusEl, 'cs-focus' );
        }
    }

    /**
     * add to global namespace
     */
    window.SelectFx = SelectFx;

} )( window );
```

And lastly, **classie.js**:

```
( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );
```

Comment: It legit works when I don't include those two classes. Hmmmm...

Comment: Show the styles for the `select`. Maybe the case is that you are hiding the real `select` and create another select-like element with JS but it is not the actual `select`. You know what I mean? Look at the DOM in the browser and see if the select's value is changing when you click on different options

Comment: it works in the filddle .https://jsfiddle.net/ospL891x/ . Are you sure no other events are bound on the select?

Comment: Let me post the styles for the select.

Comment: works in my fiddle as well.... https://jsfiddle.net/0o89pmju/71/

Comment: can you post the complete file code

Comment: Ohhh, I think I know what you mean @SebastianKaczmarek. When I went into the cs-select.css file there's a selector of .cs-select select {display: none; } and when I comment this portion out then another select box is shown right under the picture provided about. When the values are selected, the h2 value changes like it should.

Comment: Ok, I've provided the styling files as well.

Comment: And when you are changing the values in select-like element, is the real select changing too? If no, then the select-like element is not triggering the `change` event and this is where you should look for the reason of the problem

Comment: Surely there are also some JS files, which are responsible for creating the "select". Make sure that there is some kind of logic which triggers the `change` event

Comment: I'm gonna check on that, but I did forget to post the JS files as well.

Comment: Added the two JS files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the select classes that you had used. A simple googling gave this [SelectInspiration](https://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/) , as my peers have pointed out in the comments this plugin changes the apperance of the select widget (a good one i should add).

Fear not, the dev has made the plugin customisable. As per the demo files it is possible to capture the change event and override it with your needed changes.

I am presuming that there is something like this in your HTML

```
document.querySelectorAll('select.cs-select')).forEach(function (el) {
            new SelectFx(el);
 }
```

Now if we dive deep into the custom js file the dev has included. you can see

`

```
  /**SelectFx function*/
    function SelectFx( el, options ) {  
        this.el = el;
        this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
        extend( this.options, options );
        this._init();
    }`


`   /**
     * SelectFx options
     */
    SelectFx.prototype.options = {
        // if true all the links will open in a new tab.
        // if we want to be redirected when we click an option, we need to define a data-link attr on the option of the native select element
        newTab : true,
        // when opening the select element, the default placeholder (if any) is shown
        stickyPlaceholder : true,
        // callback when changing the value
        onChange : function( val ) { return false; }
    }`
```

Keeping this in mind you can just

```
function changelogic(val) {
            console.log("Your logic")
            console.log(val);
        }

        document.querySelectorAll('select.cs-select')).forEach(function (el) {
            new SelectFx(el, {onChange: changelogic});
        };
```

This should set you up comfortably without needing to change much

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help.